# Stop form submission if radio button is checked

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form on FormAssembly, and I would like to stop someone submitting the form if they select the 'No' Radio Button for the question 'Are you an employer?'. I have put what I have so far in a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h5r8gud1/2/).

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('input#tfa_1904').click(function() {
  if ($('#tfa_1904').is(':checked') {
    submitButton.disabled = true;
  }
  else {
    submitButton.disabled = false;
  }
 });
});
```

submitButton code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var warning = document.getElementById("javascript-warning");
  if (warning != null) {
    warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);
  }
  var oldRecaptchaCheck = parseInt('0');
  if (oldRecaptchaCheck !== -1) {
    var explanation = document.getElementById('disabled-explanation');
    var submitButton = document.getElementById('submit_button');
    if (submitButton != null) {
      submitButton.disabled = true;
        if (explanation != null) {
          explanation.style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: What is `submitButton`? Can you post the code for that selector please?...

Comment: I have edited the post! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you don't need to check whether the radio button is checked as only one will be checked at a time. So, just capturing the click will suffice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#tfa_1904').click(function() {
        $('#submit_button').prop('disabled', true);
    });

    $('input#tfa_1903').click(function() {
        $('#submit_button').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/h5r8gud1/8/

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I want! Thank you! I have aded the js to my site (Wordpress) and it is no longer working. I do have 2 other forms on the site, on other pages, so I assume I will have to target the page as well as the form in the js too? Also there's two places where I can add the js, from within FormAssembly, or Wordpress - do you know at all which is best to add it to? I have also published the form on the site using a shortcode, I cannot change it to an iframe unfortunately. Thank you :)

Comment: There is also a captcha on the form, which, until completed, also disables the submit button - thought it was worth a mention in case it somehow overrides the new js.